# R - prevent lapply() from stopping for empty data frames

Tags: r, lapply, lm

I have the following code that creates one PDF with multiple plots. Within the code, "files" contains the names of all the datasets I am looping through in lapply().

```
pdf(file="plot.pdf")
par(mfrow=c(3,3), oma=c(1,1,8,1))
Test <- lapply(1:length(files), function(x) {
a <- as.data.table(read.csv(files[x], header = TRUE))
plot(col 1 ~ col 2, a, main = paste("R=", summary(lm(col 1 ~ col 2, a))$adj.r.squared))
abline(lm(col 1 ~ col 2, a), col = "red")
})
dev.off()
```

This code works if all the datasets have values. When an empty dataset is encountered, the linear model function [lm()] gives the following error and stops the loop.

```
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  0 (non-NA) cases
```

The PDF will be exported but will only contain plots made before the error. Is there a way that the error can be ignored so that the code continues to loop through the remainder of the datasets (which may actually have data)?

Comment: `if(nrow(a) == 0) return()`?

Comment: if(nrow(a)==0) return() didn't work. It returned the following error: Error in xj[i] : invalid subscript type 'closure'

Comment: Wrap your code that may fail in a `try({}, silent = TRUE)`

Comment: Maybe `if (length(a)){}`?

Answer (score 2):

A simple method would be to wrap the offending code in a try statement:

```
pdf(file="plot.pdf")
par(mfrow=c(3,3), oma=c(1,1,8,1))
Test <- lapply(1:length(files), function(x) {
  a <- as.data.table(read.csv(files[x], header = TRUE))
  try({
    plot(col 1 ~ col 2, a, main = paste("R=", summary(lm(col 1 ~ col 2, a))$adj.r.squared))
    abline(lm(col 1 ~ col 2, a), col = "red")
  }, silent = TRUE)
})
dev.off()
```

`try` will instruct R to run the code detailed in the expression. The `silent = TRUE` argument will instruct R to suppress any errors.